# Python TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #1 to a sequence

Tags: python-2.7

doing some data wrangling from an example in O'Reilly's "Python for Data Analysis."

We start with data of the following format:

```
In [108]: data.CATEGORY[:5]
Out[108]: 
0          1. Urgences | Emergency, 3. Public Health, 
4                            1. Urgences | Emergency, 
5                       5e. Communication lines down, 
6    4. Menaces | Security Threats, 4e. Assainissem...
7                      4. Menaces | Security Threats, 
Name: CATEGORY, dtype: object
```

The book then lays out a procedure for removing the periods and '|' from each entry with the goal of creating a dictionary, using the following definitions;

```
def get_all_categories(cat_series):
    cat_sets = (set(to_cat_list(x)) for x in cat_series)
    return sorted(set.union(*cat_sets))

def get_english(cat):
    code, names = cat.split('.')
    if '|' in names:
        names = names.split(' | ')[1]
    return code, names.strip()
```

The first step goes fine, creating the list of unique categories;

```
In [109]: all_cats = get_all_categories(data.CATEGORY)

In [110]: all_cats[:5]
Out[110]: 
['1. Urgences | Emergency',
 '1a. Highly vulnerable',
 '1b. Urgence medicale | Medical Emergency',
 '1c. Personnes prises au piege | People trapped',
 '1d. Incendie | Fire']
```

However, using the second definition results in the following;

```
In [116]: english_mapping = dict(get_english(x) for x in all_cats)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-116-e69c3419c341> in <module>()
----> 1 english_mapping = dict(get_english(x) for x in all_cats)

TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #1 to a sequence
```

A little help for a Python noob please :)

Comment: I do not get this error when run on the input data you have provided.

Comment: Just tried it again on a different computer and I continue to get the same TypeError. I forgot to type in the following definition which is necessary for the get_all_categories definition:

    `def to_cat_list(catstr):
        stripped = (x.strip() for x in catstr.split(','))
        return [x for x in stripped if x]`

Not sure how you got the code to work without that Scott...

Comment: @user3334415 I also did not get an error.  Link here: http://codepad.org/4uYUiIoS Caveat: I took a shortcut and simply used the excerpt you posted for `all_cats` (the first five elements) in a direct assignment, but I don't know enough about the full data you are loading to know whether that would cause your outcome to be different.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution:

1. "cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #1 to a sequence"---because there is null value in the expression "get_english(x) for x in all_cats", so it can't be converted into a dictionary;
2. Why?

> ```
> def get_english(cat):
>     code,names=cat.split('.')
>     if '|' in names:
>         names=names.split('|')[1]
>         return code,names.strip()
> ```

----Here is the problem,the last line shouldn't indent，if not,you will get some value null.